# Coproducts exist in the category of groups (need help understanding proof)

Tags: group-theory, category-theory, proof-explanation

First let me put down the proof (by Serge Lang)

[image: proof]

I think this proof is beautiful but there are several points I can't get over. Here are my questions:

1. What does "$S_i$ be denumerable if $G_i$ is finite" mean? Is it even possible to pick $S_i = \mathbb{N}$ in this case, since $\mathbb{N}$ is denumerable? Or should I consider $S_i$ to be a random countable set containing all elements of $G_i$?
2. Why would we assume that $\operatorname{card}(G)=\operatorname{card}(S)$? I don't understand his motivation by embedding $G$ as a factor in a product $G \times S_\gamma$.
3. Why $f_i \circ g_*=g_i$? If I'm right, the universal element, which determines the coproduct, is $\{f_i:G_i \to G\}$. There should be a unique morphism $g_*$ in the category of groups such that $g_* \circ f_i = g_i$, by definition of coproduct. I'm assuming that writing $f_i \circ g_*$ is a typo. What he was doing in the last two paragraphs is proving the existence and uniqueness of the desired morphism $g_*$.

---

In case you are not familiar with Lang's terminology, I'm writing down some terminologies that you may find different on other books.

> Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category. An object $P$ of $\mathcal{C}$ is called **universally attracting** if there exists a unique morphism of each object of $\mathcal{C}$ into $P$, and is called **universally repelling** if for every object of $\mathcal{C}$ there exists a unique morphism of $P$ into this object. (When context clear, we shall call $P$ as above **universal**. In this proof, being universal means being universal repelling)

> Let $\{A_i\}$ be a family of objects in a category $\mathcal{C}$. By their **coproduct** one means a pair $(S,\{f_i\}_{i\in{I}})$ consisting of an object $S$ and a family of morphisms
> $$
> \{f_i:A_i \to S\}
> $$
> Satisfying the following property. Given a family of morphisms $\{g_i: A_i \to C\}$, there exists a unique morphism $h: S \to C$ such that $h \circ f_i = g_i$ for all $i$.

---

Anyway, feel free to answer the question or point out what is wrong with me. Appreciated.

Comment: 1. You can pick $S_i=\mathbf{N}$, it's just not practical, since you don't want to identify it to $\mathbf{N}$, and want distinct notation when $i$ varies. Maybe avoid "random" when meaning "arbitrary". All you want about $S_i$ is to be an infinite countable set.

Comment: 2. he first observes that one can boil down to $|G|\le |S|$ (shrinking $G$ to the subgroup generated by the images), and then boils down to the case $|G|=|S|$ (enlarging $G$ with a stupid direct product).

Comment: 3. yes one should read $g_*\circ f_i$

Comment: @YCor Thank you for your reply. Could you give an elaboration of 'stupid direct product'? I think I get the idea: as long as $G$ exists, we can make it larger (up to $S$). But I can't see the way it works. I think it's like, given a $G$, we can derive a larger group  $G'$ from $G \times S_\gamma$. But how?

Comment: Actually one needs to embed $G$ into a group of cardinal $|S|$ (which is infinite), assuming $|G|\le |S|$. Then for any group structure on $S$, the direct product $G\times S$ makes the job (such a group structure exists; this relies on the axiom of choice in general; namely one uses the existence of a bijection from $S$ to the set of finite subsets of $S$, which is naturally a group under symmetric difference).

Comment: @YCor I think I get it. The enlarged group $G'$ is actually $G \times S_\gamma$. The crux is, $\operatorname{card}(G \times S)=\operatorname{max}(\operatorname{card}(G),\operatorname{card}(S))$, which is based on the axiom of choice. Also, it can be seen why we have to force all $S_i$ to be infinite.